# generate list of means from lists of floats python

Tags: python-3.x, list, mean

I'm trying to write simple code that will take floats in two lists, find the mean between the two numbers in the same position in each list, and generate a new list with the updated means. For example, with **list_1** and **list_2**,

```
list_1: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
list_2: [6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
list_3: []

for i in list_1:
    for x in list_2:
        list_3.append((x+i)/2)
print (list_3)
```

Find the mean between floats in two lists and create a new list such that:

```
list_3 = [3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5]
```

I tried creating a for loop but (for obvious reasons) doesn't iterate the way that I want it to. The **output** is:

```
[3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a generator expresion like:

#### Code:

```
[sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

#### How:

The function [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) allows easy iteration through multiple lists at the same time.  From there these values can be fed into `sum()` and `len()` as shown.

#### Test Code:

```
list_1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
list_2 = [6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]

list_3 = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(list_1, list_2)]
print(list_3)
```

#### Results:

```
[3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5]
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!